# Wrong results after checking if n2 is multiple of n1 but no error at all

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename Multiple>
void isMultiple(Multiple a,Multiple b[],Multiple c[])
{
  int t = 0;
  while(t<a)
  {
   cout<<"Pair #"<<t<<endl;
   if(c[t]%b[t]==0)//checks the condition if n2 is multiple of n1
     {
        cout<<"TRUE:"<<c[t]<<" is a multiple of "<<b[t]<<endl;
     }
   else
     {
        cout<<"FALSE:"<<c[t]<<" is a multiple of "<<b[t]<<endl;
     }
    cout<<endl;
    t++;
  }
}
int main()
{
   int n1[] = {};
   int n2[] = {};
   int c;
   cout<<" How many pairs?:"
   cin>>c;
   int a = 0;
   do
   {
     cout<<"Pair #"<<a<<endl;
     cout<<"Enter 1st number:";
     cin>>n1[a];
     cout<<"Enter 2nd number:";
     cin>>n2[a];
     cout<<endl;
     a++;
   }while(a<c);
   isMultiple(c,n1,n2);//function template call
return 0;
```

The results after running and testing the program are different that the expected outcome, no problem in the syntax and no error at all.

The if condition should be working fine because the 2 arrays has a counter and it should not display the same number.

Comment: Your code is not legal C++. You should create your arrays after you know what size they need to be. Even easier would be to use a vector.

Comment: "different that the expected outcome".
Please mention what is unexpected about the output?

Comment: I have several comments. Function isMultiple() returns nothing, it should return a bool. You writing in arrays before allocating the arrays no wonder your results are unpredictable. You should make n1 and n2 std::vector and push the read values. Then your template should use std::vector<Multiple> instead of Multiple for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal C++ to define an array with no size or with zero length size.

```
int n1[] = {};
```

Now clearly your compiler is accepting this because you aren't complaining about compiler errors. I suspect that your compiler is creating zero length array, which obviously is not what you want. Note that arrays do not resize themselves just because you assign data to them.

Here's one way to do this code correctly, using dynamic allocation to create arrays of the right size.

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    cout<<" How many pairs?:";
    cin>>c;
    int* n1 = new int[c]; // dynamic allocation of array
    int* n2 = new int[c]; // dynamic allocation of array
    int a = 0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Pair #"<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter 1st number:";
        cin>>n1[a];
        cout<<"Enter 2nd number:";
        cin>>n2[a];
        cout<<endl;
        a++;
    } while(a<c);
    isMultiple(c,n1,n2);//function template call
    return 0;
}
```

An even better way to do this would be to use the `std::vector` class. But maybe leave that for another time.

Comment: int array[some_variable]; is valid for GCC, that is array length assigned through a variable. I think MSVC complains about this though.

Comment: @MithilPoojary That construct is a variable length array, and you are right, accepted by gcc, but not valid C++. The OP didn't even specify a size however, unless the `{}` implies a zero length size.

Comment: @MithilPoojary Thinking about it, I'm guessing that the compiler has created a zero length array. I've updated the answer to reflect that. In any case the code is wrong and non-standard.

Comment: Thank you all for these answers, I'm just a beginner in programmer so most of you all's answer are not familiar with me but I surely will learn about it. Thanks for these helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now your code is working.I have changed array declaration type.
instead of int arr[]={}; i have created a pointer and after that I am allocating blocks of required memory using new operator.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename Multiple>
void isMultiple(Multiple a,Multiple *b,Multiple *c)
{
  int t = 0;
  while(t<a)
  {
   cout<<"Pair #"<<t<<endl;
   if(c[t]%b[t]==0)//checks the condition if n2 is multiple of n1
     {
        cout<<"TRUE:"<<c[t]<<" is a multiple of "<<b[t]<<endl;
     }
   else
     {
        cout<<"FALSE:"<<c[t]<<" is a multiple of "<<b[t]<<endl;
     }
    cout<<endl;
    t++;
  }
}
int main()
{
   int *n1,*n2;
   int c;
   cout<<" How many pairs?:";
   cin>>c;
   n1=new int[c];
   n2=new int[c];
   int a = 0;
   while(a<c)
   {
     cout<<"Pair #"<<a<<endl;
     cout<<"Enter 1st number:";
     cin>>n1[a];
     cout<<"Enter 2nd number:";
     cin>>n2[a];
     cout<<endl;
     a++;
   }
   isMultiple(c,n1,n2);//function template call
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some syntax errors (I assume them to be typo here) the main error was your array initialization. This is the modified code using `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void checkMultiples(T n1, T n2) {
    if (n1.size() != n2.size())
        return;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n1.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "Pair #" << i << std::endl
                  << (n2[i] % n1[i] ? "FALSE" : "TRUE") // true if second number is a multiple of first
                  << ": " << n2[i] << " is a multiple of " << n1[i]
                  << std::endl
                  << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "How many pairs? ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> n1(n), n2(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Pair #" << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter 1st number: ";
        std::cin >> n1[i];
        std::cout << "Enter 2nd number: ";
        std::cin >> n2[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    checkMultiples(n1, n2);
    return 0;
}
```